# Angular 6 auth using cookies

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies

Any idea on how to implement cookie auth in Angular 6?
I have tried using AuthGuard but I'm not able to check if the user is authenticated or not because the cookie is HttpOnly so I can't access its content.
I need this to protect some routes.

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is a quite good tutorial: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the problem is that It must be done using cookies, I can't use jwt.

Comment: Cookies is just a way to store information in the browser. You will need some form of tokens. What do you store in the cookies? Jwt uses cookies aswell.

Comment: You won't be able to leverage an Http-Only cookie to do an authentication check on the *client-side*, however you can pass this cookie to an API endpoint to determine that and pass back a response which you can use in your route guard.

Comment: @Brandon I think I'll try what you say, but how do I send the cookie to the server? Adding `withCredentials: true` I suppose.

Comment: @Warthaxx yes, that's correct. At work, we use this exact same methodology via Okta. On a successful login at Okta, they generate an Http-Only cookie which we pass back to our APIs, which checks the cookie values.

Comment: @Brandon Ok, thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help.

Comment: why even protect the routes when you can modify the cookie anyways. You need to use jwt. Is this embedded inside of a .net page or something?

Answer (score -1):

with JWT you should save the token, you must kepp the key in the cookie.